# Group by variable and create layers from that in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, grouping

I have a large shapefile with one layer with several variables. The shapefile has US block groups that I'll use for analysis. However, as I want to use this for leaflet, I would like to create different layers/files for each state.

```
State Value1 Value2 Value3 ...
  NY    x      x      x
  CO    x      x      x 
  NY    x      x      x
```

Is there a way of grouping per state and generate a layer from that, that I can later save as a shapefile?

I know that I can do it one by one, by using the SQL query tool, but as I have 50 something states, plus different files, that would take me quite of a long time.

Comment: You can use the **Split vector layer** tool from the menubar (`Vector > Data Management Tools`) and select `State` as your unique field which would create separate layers for each state.

Answer (score 2):

[Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25814/joseph) presented the solution to this question in a comment:

You can use the **Split vector layer** tool from the menubar (Vector > Data Management Tools) and select `State` as your unique field which would create separate layers for each state.